# Unable to build frequensea

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to build the package frequensea, but I'm having errors.

I edited CMakeCache.txt to fill in the path for required libraries and I was expecting not to have more obstacles to build the software.

However, this is the output from make:

```
sdr@sdr:/home/sdr/frequensea/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target lua
[  2%] Linking C static library liblua.a
[ 75%] Built target lua
Scanning dependencies of target frequensea
[ 77%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 79%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nfile.c.o
[ 81%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o
[ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nim.c.o
[ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/noise.c.o
[ 87%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nosc.c.o
[ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nrf.c.o
[ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nut.c.o
[ 93%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/nwm.c.o
[ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/obj.c.o
[ 97%] Building C object CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/vec.c.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable frequensea
externals/lua/liblua.a(loslib.c.o): In function `os_tmpname':
/home/sdr/sdr/frequensea/externals/lua/src/loslib.c:140: warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_check_compile_error':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:80: undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderiv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:83: undefined reference to `__glewGetShaderInfoLog'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_check_link_error':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:92: undefined reference to `__glewGetProgramiv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:95: undefined reference to `__glewGetProgramInfoLog'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_shader_new':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:102: undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:103: undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:104: undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:108: undefined reference to `__glewCreateShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:109: undefined reference to `__glewShaderSource'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:110: undefined reference to `__glewCompileShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:114: undefined reference to `__glewCreateProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:115: undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:116: undefined reference to `__glewAttachShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:119: undefined reference to `__glewTransformFeedbackVaryings'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:120: undefined reference to `__glewLinkProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:129: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:130: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:131: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_shader_uniform_set_float':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:146: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:147: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:149: undefined reference to `__glewUniform1f'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:151: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_shader_free':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:155: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:156: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteShader'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:157: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteProgram'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_texture_new':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:170: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:179: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_texture_update':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:219: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_model_new':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:258: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:259: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:260: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:267: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:268: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:269: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:276: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:277: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:278: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:284: undefined reference to `__glewGenVertexArrays'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:285: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:288: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:289: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:290: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:295: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:296: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:297: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:302: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:303: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:304: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_model_load_obj':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:467: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:468: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:469: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:472: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:473: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:474: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:479: undefined reference to `__glewGenVertexArrays'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:480: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:481: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:482: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:483: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:484: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:485: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:486: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_model_free':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:498: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:499: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:500: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:501: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteVertexArrays'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_skybox_new':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:620: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:621: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:622: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:624: undefined reference to `__glewGenVertexArrays'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:625: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:626: undefined reference to `__glewEnableVertexAttribArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:627: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:628: undefined reference to `__glewVertexAttribPointer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:630: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_skybox_draw':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:652: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:654: undefined reference to `__glewUniformMatrix4fv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:656: undefined reference to `__glewUniformMatrix4fv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:658: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:662: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_skybox_free':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:671: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:672: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteVertexArrays'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `_ngl_draw_model':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:689: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:691: undefined reference to `__glewUniform1f'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:693: undefined reference to `__glewUniformMatrix4fv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:695: undefined reference to `__glewUniformMatrix4fv'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:698: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:701: undefined reference to `__glewBeginTransformFeedback'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:707: undefined reference to `__glewEndTransformFeedback'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:711: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:713: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_capture_model':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:723: undefined reference to `__glewGenTransformFeedbacks'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:726: undefined reference to `__glewGenBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:728: undefined reference to `__glewBindTransformFeedback'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:730: undefined reference to `__glewBindBuffer'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:733: undefined reference to `__glewBufferData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:735: undefined reference to `__glewBindBufferBase'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:743: undefined reference to `__glewGetBufferSubData'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:748: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteBuffers'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:750: undefined reference to `__glewDeleteTransformFeedbacks'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_font_new':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:805: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:807: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:809: undefined reference to `__glewGetUniformLocation'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:811: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:834: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/src/ngl.c.o: In function `ngl_font_draw':
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:903: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:905: undefined reference to `__glewUniform2f'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:907: undefined reference to `__glewUniform1f'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:909: undefined reference to `__glewActiveTexture'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:913: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:918: undefined reference to `__glewBindVertexArray'
/home/sdr/frequensea/src/ngl.c:920: undefined reference to `__glewUseProgram'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/build.make:365: recipe for target 'frequensea' failed
make[2]: *** [frequensea] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/frequensea.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Editing the CMakeLists.txt is not the right thing. You should add the paths to the libraries to the CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH which you path to the CMake call. Or use CMake-GUI.

Comment: Launch the build with `make VERBOSE=1` to see the commands executed. Then directly run the linker command that you'll see, try to make it work. Then figure out what to change, so CMake can pass correct arguments to the linker command (add some `message(${MY_VARIABLE})` calls into `CMakeLists.txt` to debug the variables that you want to inspect).